# D7 Views 3.4 Related Items View

Tags: nodes, views

Using D7 Views 3.4 and References module.- I have a content type called "Gloves" which has a node reference to a content type called "Glove Type".

What I need is to be able to see other gloves from the same "Glove Type" when viewing a glove node.

Ex:

Glove name = Outback, Glove Type = Mens.
I need to be able to display the names of other Glove Types within Mens while viewing the Outback node.

So somehow I need to dynamically pull the "Glove Type" from the current node, and then display a list of nodes from the same "Glove Type" (excluding the one being viewed)

I've been trying all types of contextual filters, arguments etc but can't get it right.

Appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using entity-reference module ?

Comment: No, I'm using References module.  Thanks for reminding me...I'll edit my question now.